# MoolRamayanam how to get a copy

Tags: ramayana, resource

Many years ago  (mid 60s) the sahitya syllabus of the pramana patriya course at the Sanskrit University in Benaras included the Moolaramayanam. A very slim volume which summarised the whole epic in a small number of slokas (100 or 200 or so I can't remember). Where can I obtain a copy of this? I got my original copy at Motilal Banarsidass in the old town but I can't find it listed anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Is this the one: https://archive.org/details/MulaRamayan1935GuruPrasadShastri/page/n3/mode/2up ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - Good Find. How about writing an answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Go ahead! Post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Mula Ramayana is nothing but the 100 verses of [Sarga 1 of Balakanda of Valmiki Rayamana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga1/bala_1_frame.htm). Are you looking for the book in particular or just the 100 verses?

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful. I'd still like a hard copy. No luck with Motilal and will continue trying the other indological booksellers I see listed on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the Mool Ramayana in Sanskrit then here is the link:

https://archive.org/download/in.ernet.dli.2015.345549/2015.345549.Mool-Ramayana.pdf

If you are looking for the Mool Ramayana in Hindi then here is the link:

https://epustakalay.com/sanskrit/book/12694-mool-ramayana-by-ramnath-lal/